# Rewriting the integral $\mathrm{erf}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-x}^x e^{-t^2} dt.$

Tags: integration, special-functions, definite-integrals, error-function

I'm trying to implement an equation into a programming language which doesn't have functions for integrals. However as it's many years since I've had any math exercise I'm having some trouble understanding how I can simplify the following equation.

$$\mathrm{erf}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-x}^x e^{-t^2} dt.$$

As an example would it be correct to refactor the equation as follows?

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cdot \left(x \cdot e^{-x^2}+(-x) \cdot e^{x^2}\right)$$

Please forgive me if I'm completely off target! As I said, it's been quite a few years since I've had integrals.

Comment: It can't be simplifed. Your programming language probably has a function for it though. It is called the "error function".

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find many facts about the error function here: [Error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

For example have a look at the sections *Taylor series* and *Approximation with elementary functions* - they might help you to implement this function into your programming language.