# Integrate over a triangle in the 2D normal distribution

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

I'd like to evaluate following expression efficiently (numerically).

$$g_a(x) := \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \int_0^{at} e^{-s^2} dsdt$$

If I want a given fixed accuracy, and evaluate both integrals using e.g. a summed quadrature formula for each integral, the cost is about $O(ax^2)$. Is there a better way than this naive one?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-to-accurately-calculate-the-error-function-erfx-with-a-computer) and also [here](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Sylvain.Chevillard/download/papers/ChevillardRevolRNC8.pdf), though the second might be more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter noted, implicit in the question is whether it is better to do 2D quadrature than evaluate an error function at each sample point of a 1D quadrature; i.e., is there structure in the definition of the error function that allows speedup relative to the naive quadrature implementation? So I wrote a little code to find out: Using `boost::math::erf` and `std::exp`, I determined that it is *faster* to evaluate `erf` than `std::exp`:

```
Run on (8 X 3700 MHz CPU s)
------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Time           CPU Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------
BM_Erf<float>                 5 ns          5 ns  110919662
BM_Erf<double>                9 ns          9 ns   73097986
BM_Erf<long double>           8 ns          8 ns   73967212
BM_Bell<float>               11 ns         11 ns   59276009
BM_Bell<double>              12 ns         12 ns   52942894
BM_Bell<long double>        197 ns        197 ns   13041274
```

So it's faster to evaluate `erf` than `exp` (though keep in mind that boost is not bound by the 1ULP accuracy goal of the standard library math functions). Next you just need a good quadrature rule, say, [tanh-sinh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature) for small $x$ and trapezoidal for large. These will converge exponentially in about 30 function evaluations (double precision), so your total compute time should be about $(12+9)*30 \mathrm{ns} \approx 0.5\mu s$.

That's as fast as I can think to get it.

Code to compute the speed:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

template<typename Real>
static void BM_Erf(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<Real> dis(0, 1000);
    auto s = dis(gen);
    Real y;
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(y = boost::math::erf(s));
    }
    std::ostream cnull(nullptr);
    cnull << y;
}

template<typename Real>
static void BM_Bell(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<Real> dis(0, 1000);
    auto s = dis(gen);
    Real y;
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(y = std::exp(-s*s));
    }
    std::ostream cnull(nullptr);
    cnull << y;
}


BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_Erf, float);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_Erf, double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_Erf, long double);

BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_Bell, float);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_Bell, double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_Bell, long double);


BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```