# Approximation - how to graph a probability density function?

Tags: calculus

I was wondering how to graph a probability density function with the following information: https://prnt.sc/lpvnxm.

Comment: It's better to write the full question here rather than linking to an image. Also, you'll get a better response if you explain what you've tried.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97/3301 and information on [pdf or erf](http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap2.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

$$ f(x) =  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ 2 \pi \sigma }}  \exp \bigg( - \frac{ (x - \mu )^2 }{2 \sigma^2 } \bigg)$$

Since $e^x \approx 1+x $

the Quadratic approximation must be

$$  Q(x) = K \bigg(1   - \frac{ (x - \mu )^2 }{2 \sigma^2} \bigg)$$
Only valid for $|x - \mu | < \sqrt2 \sigma $

$K$ is a normalization constant that you can calculate by making the requirement

$$  \int _{\mu- \sqrt2 \sigma}  ^{\mu-+\sqrt2 \sigma} Q(x)dx = 1$$