# Gaussian estimate

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find some $a\gt 0$ such that $$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt\leq e^{-a}$$ Any good method to do so?
I'm looking for an analytical argument rather than a numerical solution.
Edit: there was a typo in the integral.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)+1\right)\leq e^{-a}\to a\leq \log (2)-\log \left(\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)+1\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. However I am looking for something that doesn't use erf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the problem general, you search for $a$ such that, for a given $x$,
$$\int_{-x}^{+x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt\leq e^{-a}$$ that is to say
$$\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\leq e^{-a}$$ First, we can solve the equation using some approximation. For example
$$\text{erf}(t)\sim \sqrt{1-\exp\Big(-\frac 4 {\pi}\,\frac{1+\alpha\, t^2}{1+\beta \,t^2}\,t^2 \Big)}$$ where
$$\alpha=\frac{10-\pi ^2}{5 (\pi -3) \pi } \qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=\frac{120-60 \pi +7 \pi ^2}{15 (\pi -3) \pi }$$ so
$$a > -\frac 12 \log \Bigg[1-\exp\Bigg(-\frac{2 x^2 \left(\alpha  x^2+2\right)}{\pi  \left(\beta  x^2+2\right)} \Bigg)\Bigg]$$

Using $x=2$, this approximation gives $a >0.04673$ while the exact solution would be $a >0.04657$.

We can have much better using the second approximation I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-to-accurately-calculate-the-error-function-operatornameerfx-with-a-co).

Answer (score 0):

with standard procedure you can see that

$$\int_{-\infty}^2 \phi(x)dx\approx 0.97725$$

thus you can find an approximated value for $a$, that is

$$a\approx0.023$$

and it is valid with $=$ instead of $\leq$

Comment: Hi, sorry for not making it clear earlier, but I'm looking for an analytical argument rather than a number.